# Sending email from GCE or AWS on behalf of users

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp, google-compute-engine

How could I use Google Compute Engine (or a similar service, like AWS) to send email on behalf of users via their SMTP server?

I am interested in building an online email client which allows users to enter their SMTP and POP servers and send/receive email, like they would with their desktop clients. GCE [blocks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) all SMTP ports to prevent abuse and recommends using a mail service like SendGrid instead. However, after researching dozens of these services, they all seem to only support transactional email using their own SMTP servers, or possibly a pre-cleared smtp server. I simply want to send email using the *user's* SMTP server (*ex* smtp.mail.yahoo.com), just like they would if they were using a desktop client.

I realize I could host my own servers but I am not interested in maintaining the infrastructure. I would like to host everything on a cloud service. Is there any way I can work around Google's restrictions with an existing service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm sure you are aware, you would have to have the user enter their SMTP server information and account credentials. You would then use that information to connect to their SMTP server.

By default AWS EC2 instances have SMTP traffic on port 25 rate limited. To remove this limitation, you would need to fill out and submit the following form:
https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Comment: Services that allow users to send outgoing mail via SMTP *should* expose their [MSA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent) on port 587 [like Yahoo does](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4724.html), which EC2 doesn't restrict... or sometimes they (wrongly) use port 465... but not port 25, which *should* only be used for MTA.  Still, yikes to the idea of requiring users to hand over their email credentials, which is probably a violation of many services' TOS/AUP, but would indeed be necessary for this to work.

Comment: I agree that it's hardly ideal, however there's certainly precedent for it. Google does it already for users who use gmail to send email via another service.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to send mail as a [Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send), [Hotmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#SendMessageOnTheFly), or [Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/mail/) user, you'll probably want to call the service's API to have the server send mail on the user's behalf. There are several benefits of this:

1. You'll need to get authorization from users (usually via an OAuth flow)
   in order to access their mail. This means that users shouldn't be
   surprised that you're sending mail from their accounts, and they'll
   have some control over your access.
2. The mail will be signed and come from the appropriate IP addresses to
   comply with the various spam-control mechanisms set up by those
   companies. Without this, it's likely that the mail you send will end
   up in the bit-bucket of the recipient.
3. By using the API, the service should be able to keep a copy of the
   sent mail in the user's outgoing mail folder. This will let the user
   see and search for the original message sent if they want.

Unfortunately, this may also mean that each mail service you want to send from will need separate integration, and that you may not be able to send as the user's email address from smaller providers.

Note that the [App Engine mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) allows you to send mail as the currently logged-in user (when logging in, users have a similar consent screen to the OAuth process mentioned above).

Comment: However the app engine mail api only seems to work for "Gmail or Google-hosted domain accounts". Is here no clean solution for sending email to an arbitrary SMTP server via Google's cloud services?

Comment: Yes, this only works for Google-hosted email accounts.

Comment: As I mentioned above, Google doesn't have spam-controls set up to allow them to send as some other service (see item #2).